# Electron: Express.js server queries Mongo DB before it's ready

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, electron

A demo app I'm building uses **Express** to serve some **React** code that's watered by a **MongoDB** instance running on *mLab* and retrieved by SuperAgent calls in my main React code (loaded via *index.html*).

Starting the server and viewing in browser works great, I'm trying to create a desktop version with Electron and am running into a problem with my initial database query on the default ('/') GET route.

In short, using Superagent, my app tries to reach the database before it's connected, and the first query comes back empty. If I refresh the page, everything is there, so it is connecting eventually, it's just that the timing has somehow changed since moving to electron.

This is my express server since I moved to electron:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = require('app');
const BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');

const express = require('express'),
    db = require('./model/db'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path');

const expressApp = express();

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
var mainWindow = null;

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform != 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

function onListening() {
  mainWindow.loadURL('http://127.0.0.1:3000');
  //mainWindow.toggleDevTools();
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
app.on('ready', function() {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});

    expressApp.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

    expressApp.use(bodyParser.json());
    expressApp.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    expressApp.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './')));

    expressApp.get('/', function(req, res) {
      res.render('index');
    });

    expressApp.get('/tasks/all', db.readAllTasks);
    expressApp.post('/tasks/createTask', db.createTask);
    expressApp.delete('/tasks/deleteTask/:id', db.deleteTask);
    expressApp.put('/tasks/updateTask/:id', db.updateTask);

    server = http.createServer(expressApp);
    server.listen(expressApp.get('port'), function(){console.log("Listenning!")});
    server.on('listening', onListening);

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
});
```

Before that the server just looked like:

```
var express = require('express');
var db = require('./model/db');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './')));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});

app.get('/tasks/all', db.readAllTasks);
app.post('/tasks/createTask', db.createTask);
app.delete('/tasks/deleteTask/:id', db.deleteTask);
app.put('/tasks/updateTask/:id', db.updateTask);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

I'm thinking likely, all I need to do is move my res.render into a callback of some kind?

Alternatively, maybe something in my db.js needs to change. Here is a short version:

```
var Task = mongoose.model( 'Task', taskSchema );
mongoose.connect( '<connection string>' );

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function(){
  console.log('Connected to mongoDB');
});

var allTasks = db.collection('tasks');

function readAllTasks(req, res) {
  var holster = []
  allTasks.find({}).forEach(function(doc){
    holster.push(doc);    
    }, function(){
        res.send(holster);
    });
}
exports.readAllTasks = readAllTasks;
```

The error I get says allTasks is undefined, then right after that error I get "Connected to mongoDB" logged to console, and then if I refresh I can get data from the DB no problem.

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a native answer, but I did find a small js file called [wait-for-mongo](https://github.com/arunoda/wait-for-mongo) that should allow you to quickly fix your issue.  Based on their documentation, you could wrap your res.render like so:

```
var waitForMongo = require('wait-for-mongo');

waitForMongo('<connection string>', {timeout: 1000 * 60* 2}, function(err) {
  if(err) {
    console.log('timeout exceeded');
  } else {
   console.log('mongodb comes online');
   res.render();
 }
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick response! I think for me, a quick fix isn't as interesting as structuring the app correctly and understanding why it changed when I moved to electron. What is bugging me is why I didn't need to wait before, but now I do.

Answer (score 0):

So simply enough, all I had to do was bump up the require statement for the database.

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = require('app');
const BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');
const db = require('./model/db')

const express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path');

const expressApp = express();
```

my console reports that it's listenning and THEN it tells me it connected to the DB, but the data is loaded on first page load anyhow.
Kind of strange. I think a better solution would be to only start the server listening once DB was loaded but this does work for now.